# Error for Test Class on Controller

Tags: unit-test, controller, class

I have a pretty simple test class on a controller, which worked fine in my developer environment.  However, I am now moving it to a sandbox and I'm running into an error:

**System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, AccountTrigger: execution of BeforeInsert
caused by: System.NullPointerException: Argument cannot be null.
Class.TriggerHandlerAccount.mapRegions: line 94, column 1
Class.TriggerHandlerAccount.beforeInsert: line 19, column 1
Trigger.AccountTrigger: line 6, column 1: []**

I know it's being caused by a trigger class that was created by a vendor for my organization, but I can'f figure out what I need to change in my test classes to avoid the error.  Can anyone help?

**Test Class for Controller:**

```
@Istest
private class TestControllerShortForm
{
    static testMethod void testSFController1()
    {    
        Account acct1 = TestCreateRecords.createAcct(0);
        insert acct1;

        Opportunity opp1 = TestCreateRecords.createOppNewSF(acct1.Id);
        insert opp1;

        Short_Form__c ESF1 = new Short_Form__c();
            ESF1.Sales_Representative__c = acct1.AM_owner__c;
            ESF1.Opportunity__c = opp1.Id;
            ESF1.Partner_Contact__c = '00337000006fBvQ';
            ESF1.Term_Length__c = 12;
            ESF1.Term_Metric__c = 'Months';
            ESF1.Additional_Terms__c = 'Test Test Test';

        ApexPages.StandardController SF1 = new ApexPages.standardController(opp1);
        VF_ShortFormController SFCont1 = new VF_ShortFormController(SF1);
        SFCont1.ESF.add(ESF1);
        SFCont1.ShortForm();
        SFCont1.save();

    }
}
```

**Class Creating Records for Test Class:**

```
public class TestCreateRecords {


// create and insert a new Account record.
    public static Account createAcct(Integer i){ 

    Account acct = new Account();
        acct.Name = 'Test' + i;
        acct.Language__c = 'English';
        acct.Industry = 'Automotive';
        acct.CurrencyIsoCode = 'USD';
        acct.Legal_Name__c = 'Test' + i;
        acct.Region__c = 'NA-US-NE';
        acct.BillingCity = 'New York';
        acct.BillingState = 'New York';
        acct.BillingCountry = 'United States';

    return acct;

    }


// create and insert a new Opportunity record that has the newly created Account record as its master record.
    public static Opportunity createOppNew (Id acctId){ 
        Opportunity opp2 = new Opportunity();
            opp2.AccountId = acctId;
            opp2.Name = 'Test Opportunity - ';
            opp2.StageName = System.Label.Eng_OppStage3;
            opp2.CloseDate = date.newinstance(2020,1,31);
            opp2.Amount = 1000;
            opp2.Region__c = 'NA-US-NE';
            opp2.Type = 'New Customer';
            opp2.Website_s__c = 'www.test.com; www.test2.com; www.test3.com';
        return opp2;
    }

// create and insert a new Opportunity record that has the newly created Account record as its master record. Used for Short Form.
    public static Opportunity createOppNewSF (Id acctId){ 
        Opportunity opp2a = new Opportunity();
            opp2a.AccountId = acctId;
            opp2a.Name = 'Test Opportunity - ';
            opp2a.StageName = System.Label.Eng_OppStage3;
            opp2a.CloseDate = date.newinstance(2020,1,31);
            opp2a.Amount = 1000;
            opp2a.Region__c = 'NA-US-NE';
            opp2a.Type = 'New Customer';
            opp2a.Website_s__c = 'www.test.com; www.test2.com; www.test3.com';
        return opp2a;
    }
}
```

**Class Throwing Error:**

```
public with sharing class TriggerHandlerAccount {
    private boolean isExecuting = false;

    public TriggerHandlerAccount(boolean initIsExecuting) {
        isExecuting = initIsExecuting;
    }

    public void beforeInsert(List<Account> newAccounts) {
        setType(newAccounts);
        mapRegions(newAccounts);
        UpdateEnglishName(newAccounts, null);
    }

    public void beforeUpdate(List<Account> newAccounts, map<id, Account> oldAccountMap) {
        mapRegions(newAccounts);
        UpdateEnglishName(newAccounts, oldAccountMap);
    }

    public void afterInsert(List<Account> newAccounts) {
        updateRegionField(newAccounts, 'isInsert', newAccounts.size());
        accountHierarchyLeadSourceCalculation(new List<Account>(), newAccounts, 'isInsert', newAccounts.size());
    }


    private void UpdateEnglishName (List<Account> newAccounts, map<id, Account> oldAccountMap){
        for (Account account : newAccounts) {
            system.debug('oldAccountMap = ' + oldAccountMap);
            system.debug('oldAccountMap = ' + account.English_Account_Name__c);
            if ((oldAccountMap == null && account.English_Account_Name__c == null) ||
            (oldAccountMap != null && account.Name != oldAccountMap.get(account.id).Name && account.English_Account_Name__c == oldAccountMap.get(account.id).English_Account_Name__c))
            FillUpEnglishName(account);
        }
    }

    private void FillUpEnglishName (Account account) {
        if (account.Name == null || account.Name.trim() == '') return;
        String[] chars = account.Name.split('');
        // the 1st element in an Apex '' split is garbage; remove it:
        chars.remove(0);
        System.debug(chars);
        // change a char:
        string SC = SpecialCharacters__c.getInstance().Characters__c;
        boolean english = true;
        for (String c : chars) {
            if (!c.containsAny(SC))
                english = false;
        }
        system.debug('english = ' + english);
        if (english)
            account.English_Account_Name__c = account.Name;
    }


    private void setType(List<Account> newAccounts) {
        // If the Account is created with no Type but was converted from a Lead that had
        //    a Lead Type, set the Type from the Lead Type

        for (Account newAccount: newAccounts) {
            if (newAccount.Lead_Type__c != Null && newAccount.Type == Null) {
                newAccount.Type = newAccount.Lead_Type__c;
            }
        }
    }

    private void mapRegions(List<Account> newAccounts) {
        AccountRegionManager regionManager = new AccountRegionManager();
        Region_Mapper_Settings__c errorMessage = Region_Mapper_Settings__c.getInstance();
        for (Account newAccount: newAccounts) {
            String region = regionManager.getRegion(newAccount.BillingCountry, newAccount.BillingState);
            if (region != null) {
                newAccount.Region__c = region;
            } else {
                newAccount.addError(errorMessage.Invalid_Mapping_Message__c);
            }
        }
    }

    public static Boolean accountHierarchyLeadSourceCalculationEnable = true; 

     private void updateRegionField(List<Account> newAccounts, String triggerEvent, Integer triggerSize) {

        Boolean needUpdateRegion = false;
        map<Id , Account> accountsmap =  new map<Id, Account>();
        List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();

         for(Integer i = 0; i < triggerSize; i++){
            Account tempaccount = new Account(id = newAccounts[i].id);
            if(triggerEvent == 'isInsert') 
                needUpdateRegion = newAccounts[i].Region__c == '' || newAccounts[i].Region__c == ' ' || newAccounts[i].Region__c == null;

            if (needUpdateRegion) 
            {
                accountsmap.put(newAccounts[i].OwnerId , newAccounts[i]);
            }
         }

         for(User u : [SELECT Id, Region__c FROM User WHERE Id IN :accountsmap.keyset()]){
                   Account tempaccount = new Account(id = accountsmap.get(u.id).id) ; 
                   tempaccount.Region__c = u.Region__c;
                   system.debug('Region to update: '+ tempaccount.Region__c);
                   accounts.add(tempaccount);
         }

         if (!accounts.isempty())
            update accounts;
     }
}
```

Comment: are you mocking the custom settings in the test class?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is the issue for your test class. But you are using a hardcoded id for "Partner_Contact__c". Most likely this id will not exist in your sandbox.

```
ESF1.Partner_Contact__c = '00337000006fBvQ';
```

According to Salesforce best practices you should always create your own testdata.

Comment: Thanks @Nielsm.   I changed my code to create my own data, but I still get the same error.

Comment: What is Region_Mapper_Settings__c? A Custom Setting? Did you add some testdata to your custom setting before executing your test? If you don't create it in your test class it is not visible during your test execution as well.

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't realize that was a custom setting.  I added the line:  insert new Region_Mapper_Settings__c(Name='Test'); to my controller test class, but I still get the errors.  Am I adding that correctly?

Comment: U are using "Invalid_Mapping_Message__c" field of that custom setting in your code. Try to add a value for that before inserting and run your test again.